# achieving rounded corners for button with border-image-source is linear gradient

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve rounded corners for button while using border-image-source to linear gradient.

snippet is below -

button-class :card-approve-btn

CSS:-

```
.card-approve-btn {
    width: 85px;
   height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #485564;
    font-size: 14px;
  line-height :10px;
  font-weight: 600;

  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(291deg, #ffb37c, #f9514f);
  border-image-slice: 1;

}
```

using above css is resulting in edgy corners. and, after googling, i got to know that it is not possible to have both border radius and linear-gradient. Is it Really Impossible?
 If No, Then please suggest if anyone has answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply the gradient as the main background then use a pseudo element above it to hide it and keep only the border part visible:

```css
.card-approve-btn {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(291deg, #ffb37c, #f9514f);
  padding:0 20px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #485564;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  z-index:0;
}

.card-approve-btn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* specify the value of border width here */
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  /* --- */
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-approve-btn">
  Approve
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.But, Now i am facing one more issue,button text is not showing up,it shows up only when i define content:'approve' and removed line-height. Basically i want to show button label as "Approve" with given style and it should be vertically aligned.

Comment: @himanshusharma ok am gonna update the answer with content ;)

Comment: @himanshusharma check my answer again, i added content and more styles to handle it :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for your efforts.But,it is still not in exactly in center.:(  and,only on defining content:'Approve' it is showing 'Approve' label.

Comment: @himanshusharma did you copy all the CSS ? i made many changes ...

Comment: @himanshusharma and in the snippet here it's not centred too ? you may also have another CSS in conflict you should consider too

Comment: Yeah, I have used this complete CSS, and, even on inspecting element it show no override of alignment.Apart from it ,i see,on commenting content property,'approve' label comes automatically in center but,gradient color is also showing along.

Comment: Yes!! It worked finally!!!! i was missing some css elements..Thanks Man!!

Comment: This is the best answer I found for gradient borders with a radius.